# Adding disabled attribute removing click event permanently in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the jquery code below, Once *input1* is clicked *input2* click handler event is removed. When *input3* is clicked and the element is enabled again what happens to the click handler? 
Some tests I have been doing indicate it no longer exists, If it has been removed how do I re-enable it in the situation below?

```html
<input id="input1"> 
<input id="input2">
<input id="input3">
```

```js
$("#input1").on('click', function() {
  $("#input2").prop('disabled', 'true');
  // do something
});
$("#input3").on('click', function() {
  $("#input2").prop('disabled', 'false');
});
$("#input2").on('click', function() {
  // do something
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is incorrect. It takes a boolean value for the `disabled` property. Using the strings `"true"` and `"false"` will always evaluate to `true`.

```
$("#input1").on('click', function() {
  $("#input2").prop('disabled', true);
  // do something
});
$("#input3").on('click', function() {
  $("#input2").prop('disabled', false);
});
$("#input2").on('click', function() {
  // do something
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1usg8aa/)

Answer (score 0):

Use as below

```
  $("#input1").on('click', function() {
      $("#input2").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      // do something
  });
  $("#input3").on('click', function() {
      $("#input2").removeAttr('disabled');
  });
  $("#input2").on('click', function() {
    // do something
  });
```